# Send real time data from django rest framework to flutter

Tags: django, flutter, api, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to implement the idea of sending a real-time data from REST API (DRF) to flutter. The problem is when i update the the model, i need the last update sent directly to flutter app without needing to refresh the app every time i sent a new update from the server.

Can i achieve this through the backend? or there is another method in the flutter itself?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think django channels can be of help.. nad celery too.

Comment: How to implement it?.

Comment: when you are working with http  request you must send a request to server for fresh data.. yeap it is possible if you are working with socket

Comment: @benten I was looking for a handy method to do that but all i found is django-channels and it adds a lot of complexity to the same project. I hope there is another approach to handle this.